# R SQLITE table upate

Tags: r

I want to update a table and I am using SQLite in R. I am getting an error near "Good" systax error . I am not able to find the issue .

```
library(RSQLite)
library(ggplot2)
View(diamonds)
conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),"diamonds.db")

dbListTables(conn)
dbWriteTable(conn, "pqr", diamonds,overwrite = TRUE)
dbListTables(conn)
d_1 <-dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM pqr")

d_2 <- d_1[10,]

v_carat <- d_2$carat
v_cut <- d_2$cut
v_color <- d_2$color
#high test quality to be updated in clarity
this_p <- "high test quality"


dbExecute(conn, sprintf("UPDATE pqr SET clarity = '%s' where carat =%f and cut =%s and color =%s" ,
                                    this_p, v_carat,v_cut,v_color))
```

Please guide.
Thanks & Regards,
R

Answer (score 1):

The two strings were not quoted

```
> sprintf("UPDATE pqr SET clarity = '%s' where carat =%f and cut =%s and color =%s" ,
+                                     this_p, v_carat,v_cut,v_color)
[1] "UPDATE pqr SET clarity = 'high test quality' where carat =0.230000 and cut =Very Good and color =H"
```

If we make them `'H'` and `'Very Good'`, it should work

```
 dbExecute(conn, sprintf("UPDATE pqr SET clarity = '%s' where carat =%f and cut ='%s' and color ='%s'" ,
                                     this_p, v_carat,v_cut,v_color))
[1] 8
```

-checking

```
>  d_1 <-dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM pqr")
> 
> d_1[10,]
   carat       cut color           clarity depth table price x    y    z
10  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  59.4    61   338 4 4.05 2.39
```

-checking the data

```
> library(dplyr)
> d_1 %>%
    filter(clarity == this_p, cut == v_cut, color == v_color)
  carat       cut color           clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39
2  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  61.0    57   353 3.94 3.96 2.41
3  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  62.4    55   431 3.91 3.94 2.45
4  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  62.6    56   431 3.92 3.95 2.46
5  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  61.6    56   434 3.94 3.97 2.43
6  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  63.9    55   369 3.89 3.90 2.49
7  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  62.0    55   378 3.93 3.95 2.44
8  0.23 Very Good     H high test quality  59.2    61   389 4.00 4.04 2.38
> d_1 %>%
    filter(clarity != this_p) %>%
      head
  carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
4  0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
5  0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
6  0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48
```

Comment: It updated all the rows of pqr column clarity High test quality , thats strange.

Comment: @RBan I couldn't reproduce that issue.  I tried to filter and it gives only the update on those executed with the command

Comment: @RBan You may delete that table and start fresh with the code